# Laurent series around point $z_0=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

The function is: $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)}$. I compute that this is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1})$.
Now I need to show the radius of convergence and I started with 
$|z-1| < 1$ : $\frac{1}{z-1}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{∞}z^n$
I am not sure this is ok.

I need to compute for $|z-1| > 1$, $|z-1| < 2$ and $|z-1| > 2$ and then combined right?

Thank you!

Comment: do you mean the radius of convergence? where are you centering the Laurent Series? z=0?

Comment: I don't understand the question as it is currently written to be honest.

Comment: Around $z_0 = 1$ and I need to find area af convergence

Comment: area where the function converges

Comment: @user335652 It is usually called, I believe, *radius of convergence*

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z-1+2}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac12\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}2}\right)=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac12\left(1-\frac{z-1}2-\frac{(z-1)^2}4-\ldots\right)\right)=$$

$$=\frac1{2(z-1)}-\frac14+\frac{z-1}8-\ldots$$

and the above is valid whenever

$$\left|\frac{z-1}2\right|<1\iff|z-1|<2$$

Comment: And what is about $|z-1| < 1$, $|z-1| > 1$ and $|z - 1| > 2$? I think I need to develop around all this possibilities and then combined

Comment: @user335652 Of course, $\;|z-1|<1\implies |z-1|<2\;$ ...! What's the problem? We only need to worry about $\;\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}2}\;$ , as there is *no other* power series there.

Comment: I don't understand...I compute: $|z-1|<1$ : $\frac{1}{z-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{∞} z^n$.....for $|z-1|>1$: $\frac{1}{z-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{∞} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}$...for $|z-1|<2$ : $\frac{1}{z+1}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{∞} (-1)^n(z)^n$....for $|z-1|>2$ : $\frac{1}{z+1}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{∞}(-1)^n\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}$       I don't need that?

Comment: Your question says: Laurent series about $\;z=1\;$  and that's what you have up there.